# New site columns not available to check in list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, list-view, column, site-column

I’m experiencing an extremely annoying issue with SharePoint.

This is what I’ve done on our **SharePoint Online** tenant:

- Created a new modern SharePoint team site.  I want to track client invoices.
  -Created the initial required site columns (Invoice No, Customer, Invoice date, project code etc.).
- Created a content type from these new site columns.
- Created a list for client invoices and enabled management of content types and added my content type as the default content type on this list.
- Modified the default view on my list.
- Captured initial data (current outstanding client invoices) to test and modify my solution (list) with.
- Started to add additional required columns.  Process is a) create new site column, b) add to content type, c) modify view.

**Now my problem is that suddenly**, new columns I have added are **not** available to check if I modify the view on the list?

It seems as if the available list of columns to use in the view is just not updating anymore when I change columns on the content type.

Can anyone help?

Comment: While adding the new site column to that content type, Did you enable the option `Update all content types inheriting from this type?` ?

Comment: Hi Arulraj.  Yes that option is enabled when adding the site column to the content type.

Comment: you tried re-add the content type?

Comment: If I re-add the content type, will I:
- Lose any of the current data in my list?
- Have any issues with duplicate column names afterwards?

Thanks!!